# how can i reduce repeated code in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

i am new in laravel,
i have array like

---

```
{ 
 music : {'a' =>1, 'b'=> 2},
 video :{'c' =>10, 'd'=> 20}
}
```

i got this by using this code

---

```
$video = ResourcesVideo::where('resource_type', 'video')->get();
$music = ResourcesVideo::where('resource_type', 'music')->get();

$response['data'] = [
     "videos" => $video,
     "music" => $music,
 ];
```

on this code i got above array. so my quetions is.
how can i reduce that code. because many things are similer except where condition tried many ways but no success.

Comment: What do you mean by reduce code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array of resources and loop through it.. so in case there are more resource types in future you don't need to repeat code.

```
$resource_types = ['video', 'music'];

foreach ($resource_types as $resource_type) {
    $resources[$resource_type] = ResourcesVideo::where([
        'resource_type' => $resource_type,
    ])->get();
}

$response['data'] = $resources ?? [];
```